# C#: How to have an optional parameter referencing another parameter

Tags: c#

Is that possible for one to have something like this?

```
public void Foo(Bar someBar, int someBarValues = someBar.aInt){
  //do something
}
```

or is it literally nonsense as default values must be a runtime constant?
if that's the case, is there any work around?

Comment: You could have it be set to some magic default, then in the method you swap it with a non-compile time constant.  Seems ugly to me, but its the only way you are getting around it.

Comment: "default values must be a runtime constant" No, they must be a *compile-time* constant.

Comment: "...  runtime constant", did you meant `compile-time constant`? There's no such thing as runtime and constant

Comment: Sorry guys, I perpetuated the problem by being on auto-pilot this morning.  I edited my comment too.

Comment: Add another constructor that doesn't accept the parameter, eg. `public void Foo(Bar someBar) { int someBarValues = someBar.aInt; // etc }`